# Get object of relation n:m in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models:

1. Perfiles
2. Modulos

And the relationship between them is: Many to Many, there is a table to map relation: modulos_perfiles

I need get all "modulos" that belongs to "perfil".. I have this:

```
<% @perfiles.each do |perfil| %>
    <% @m = perfil.modulo.last %>
    <%= @m.ruta %><br/>
<% end %>
```

but I get this error:

> **undefined method "ruta" for nil:NilClass**

Where "ruta" is a column of "modulo" table.

I made this:

```
<% @perfiles.each do |perfil| %>
    <% @m = perfil.modulo.last %>
    <%= debug @m %><br/>
<% end %>
```

And I can see all attributes of @m object so:

ruby/object:Modulo

attributes:

- id: 7
- descripcion: Busquedas
- ruta: /busquedas
- created_at: 2012-11-25 02:23:51.984916000 Z
- updated_at: 2012-11-25 02:23:51.984916000 Z

But I don't understand why I cannot get this attributes with:

```
<%= @m.ruta %>
```

Any idea?, thanks!

**UPDATE**

My model classes are:

```
class Perfil < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :usuario
    has_and_belongs_to_many :modulo
end

class Modulo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :perfiles
end

class ModulosPerfiles < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**

### ANSWER

**

I don't have enough reputation to publish answer.

I've resolved:

I made this:

```
<% @perfiles.each do |perfil| %>
    <% perfil.modulo.each do |modulo| %>
        <%= modulo.ruta %><br/>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And so I can get any attribute of object "modulo".

Thanks.

Comment: might be helpful to share the two model classes

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @perfiles.each do |perfil| %>
    <% perfil.modulo.each do |modulo| %>
        <%= modulo.ruta %><br/>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```